# How can I get this argument?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have this code using HTML :

```
<button type="button" onclick="test()">{...}
</button>
```

And Here is my code in Javascript :

```
$(document).on('click', '.test_test', function (e) {

...

});
```

And this is my function :

```
function test(){
...
            }
```

The problem is that I would like to put my function test() like this :

```
$(document).on('click', '.test_test', function (e) {

...

function test(){
...
            }


});
```

But If test is inner from `$(document).on('click', '.test_test', function (e) { ... }` I can't achieve to call the function test() whereas when the function test() is outside from `$(document).on('click', '.test_test', function (e) { ... }` the function works.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Edit : What I want is actually to pass a variable which is in `$(document).on('click', '.test_test', function (e) { ...}` in the function `test()` but I don't know how to do this I try to catch the variable like this :

`<button type="button" onclick="test(variable)">{...}
</button>`

and to edit the function test like this :

`function test(variable){
alert(variable);
            }`

But it does not work ...

Comment: You seem to be mixing two approaches here. In the first you're using the old in-markup event handler, which is considered obsolete (better to keep concerns separate). In the second you're lacking the class on your element. Either should work if they're done correctly.

Comment: You also seem to be asking about two different things--calling the test function and passing it a variable. Might be time to revisit some JS fundamentals in your learning resource of choice.

Comment: The wording of your question along with your various comments are getting hard to follow. You might revise to simplify and clarify.

Comment: please edit your code to include the variable definition so we can understand how to help you better. Also... where is .test_test  ? please include it in the code. FYI `.test_test` is a selector for objects that have a "test_test" class in it. I mean: `<whatever class="test_test">something</whatever>`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply just call the function from the first?

```
$(document).on('click', '.test_test', function (e) {

...

test()

});

function test(){
...
}
```

Also, what is `.test_test`?

Comment: Actually what I want is to use a variable which is in `$(document).on('click', '.test_test', function (e) {

...

});` that is why I want to define the function test() in `$(document).on('click', '.test_test', function (e) {}`

Comment: Please keep question analysis as comments to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @JackPeter With the above you can simply just pass that variable into test and return whatever you want from test

Answer (score 0):

Reading your edits in the question, I think there are 2 possibilities of what you are trying to tell us: or you want a hard coded variable in the HTML object, or you want to pass a variable in the event's function. Here are the way of doing these 2 things:

Hard coded var:

```js
function test(str){
    console.log(str);
};
```

```html
<button class="test_test" onclick="test('whatever');">Test</button>
```

Variable in the event's function:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.test_test', function (e) {

  function test(str){
    console.log(str);
  }; 

  var msg = "Whatever2";
  test(msg);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="test_test">Test</button>
```

Comment: Actually I want to use the function test() only when I click on the button

Comment: That's what the code does. Have you clicked the run button ?

Comment: I tried but actually I have two buttons and if I put `test()` inside `$(document).on('click', '#test', function() {}` the function will run but I just want ro run the function only when I get on the button which is define  `<button type="button" id="test">{...}
</button>`

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to keep your variable in a data attribute:

```
<button type="button" class="myclass" data-myvar="myval">Button</button>
```

Then grab that in your function:

```
jQuery(document($) { // shorthand for document.ready with the $ alias
    $('.myclass').click(function() {
        let myVal = $(this).data('myvar');  // get the data variable
        test(myVal); // pass the variable to your function
    });

    // Define test() here or outside this block, depending on 
    // whether it needs access to DOM elements itself.
}):
```

https://api.jquery.com/data